# Installation with visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation

I need to create setup file for installation of these: 
-Web app  
-Win service  
-Run some sql scripts.

I wanted to do all in one setup. For example I want to make method like CreateSetup and in that method to create setup file which will contain installation/run of above 3 things.

If you have some links or idea how to do it please share.

Thank you in advance.
If I come across some solution I will post it here for others as well.

Answer (score 0):

It might very well be worth your while to sit down and learn [WIX](http://wixtoolset.org/), it seems the preferred method of dealing with more complex setups. I haven't done the tasks outlined here, but I did mange to have an installer that set up an application on a Windows Mobile device.

Looking around a bit, it does seem you can install web applications: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/115036/Creating-WIX-Installer-for-ASP-NET-Web-Application

And a windows service: http://blog.tentaclesoftware.com/archive/2009/01/01/21.aspx

And run SQL scripts: [How to run sql script to create database using Wix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906716/how-to-run-sql-script-to-create-database-using-wix)

It does appear you could even capture what is required to build a SQL string through the windows installer GUI, and use that to know where to run the SQL script, and set up any needed connection strings.